# What word should I use here

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I'm currently writing a [blog](http://2200ce.blogspot.com) and am having a question on what word should be used in here.

> Department of Secrecy **_______** Lower Leveled Species

Should the blank be filled with (from/against/or any other word).
The context is that the department in point is safeguarding its secrets from lower leveled species.

Comment: I think you answered your own question! What is the department the department of? Keeping secrets **from** lower levelled species. Hence, "Department of *Secrecy From Lower Levelled Species*".

Answer (score 1):

I think "from" is suitable here; however I think you should say "Lower Level Species", not "Lower Leveled Species".

The latter suggests that the species have somehow been caused to be at at lower level i.e. they have been leveled. I don't think that is what you mean.

"Lower Level Species" is simpler and just suggests that the species are currently at a lower level, which is what I think you mean.